# derivation of the expression "I am just going out to turn my bike round

Tags: idioms

I believe the phrase was used in london upto the 1960's as a cryptic way of saying to go (outside) to the toilet. Upto the 1960's most pubs and many houses had outside lavatories. The speaker may not of course have arrived by bike.
Is this definition correct.

Answer (score 2):

[Turn my bike around](http://www.definition-of.com/turn+my+bike+round) appears to be a phrase originated in pub culture:

> - (Verb)  To urinate. ***Originated in pub culture.*** After a few pints a drinker would go out to turn his bike around in readiness for an easy departure. This became a euphemism for visiting the toilet to urinate.
>     Usage: I'm just going to turn me bike round.

(www.definition-of.com)

also: [Turning the vicar's bike around](http://www.domeheid.com/2006/09/turning-vicars-bike-around.html):

> - The euphemism "I'm just off to turn the vicar's bike around" means "I need to go to the toilet". I am fond of this expression and can be heard using it in special company.

From [Loophemisms](http://ateacherinlondon.blogspot.it/2008/06/loophemisms_23.html):

> - Euphemisms for excretion - or “loophemisms” - are one of the most fertile areas of the English language. In his new book of euphemisms, Nigel Reees lists no less than 103 separate ways of saying the unsayable.
> - One strand of loophemism involves invoking some activity that one could not possibly be doing. Excuse me while ***I go and turn the vicar's bike around/see a man about a dog/look at the garden/water the horse.***